# beginner: <input type="folder">?

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

Disclaimer: I am new to python and django but have experience programming in Drupal.

On my django site (installed on the local user's PC), I have an html template (django) form like this:

```
<form id="blah" method="post" action=""> 
<input type="file" id="fname" size="50"/>
```

This is almost perfect. However, my application requires the user to click Browse (e.g., on Microsoft Windows) and then select not a File but a Folder (I just need the textual path provided by the  Browse button). I do not need to transfer any files or folders. I simply need that path (e.g. c:/users/name/desktop/folder)

How would you do this? jquery? html? python? django?

Comment: I'd be very interested to know why you think you need the name of a folder on the user's computer if you're not transferring any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.

Browsers have security features to restrict file access from websites. Some browsers would let you get away with a full file path if the user selects a file, but some (at least Chrome) even obfuscate that.

I believe your best bet would be flash.

Comment: Or you could use a java applet

Comment: @j_mcnally Yes, you can use a Java Applet too. I would not wish such a pain to any of my enemies though.

Comment: What if the user clicks the Browse button, selects a file, then Jquery pulls out the path from that field? (or is that disabled by the major browsers?) Also, since this is django (ultimately python) running on the same PC, are there any python tricks available?

Comment: @mellow-yellow That might work on Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome and Safari (they strip the path info). Not sure about firefox. The server framework running on the same machine would not help you much if you are not willing to go for a really screwed up hack (you might show up a gtk window). If you are looking for a cross browser solution with the least headache, I suggest creating a simple swf using Flex binary, show necessary browse panel, and invoke the javascript - actionscript bridge to pass the data to jQuery.

Comment: @j_mcnally Yes, it might even be easier with Silverlight. I never used it much but I guess it has better JavaScript interop.

Comment: For all intensive purposes i would go with flash, i just wanted to add all the possibilities. You'll see the best support for java and flash. The file api isnt super new, so you shouldn't have a problem targeting Flash 9 which should be installed almost every computer.

Comment: html5 supporting broswers may also have native support for this? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/